# Camel: how to retrieve exchange property from a ValueBuilder?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to loop over a list which is stored as an exchange property:

The following works:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        loop().simple("${property.myList.size}").
            //...
            //...
        end().
    }
}
```

But I would like to retrieve the list by its name alone, not by a Simple expression. So I am trying something like the following. But I do not understand how to retrieve the actual list object from the [`ValueBuilder`](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.7.3/org/apache/camel/builder/ValueBuilder.html)

```
loop(exchangeProperty("myList").convertTo(List.class) /*how to get the list or list size???*/).
    //...
    //...
end().
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the loop is looping a fixed number of times configured once.

You can use the dynamic router instead to do a loop like based on information from the current exchange